# How to add npm start as service in windows

Tags: node.js

I have nodejs project and need to run my node project as windows service. I tried nssm but it is not working. I often use linux . Is there another way to run "npm start" as service in windows without using nssm.

Comment: https://github.com/coreybutler/node-windows

Comment: I need two script to run . Is it possible ?

Comment: check their readme on github.